# Should we consider changing the logo temporarily?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Over on Stack Overflow, a decision [was made by the community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297859/can-stack-overflow-and-metas-logos-be-changed-temporarily-to-the-loveoverflow) to temporarily change the logo to reflect the recent US Supreme Court decision allowing gay marriage.

**Should we consider making a similar change?**

I've mocked up a sample logo we could use, although I suspect that others can do much, much better

[image]

Comment: You clearly must have missed all the chaos and resentment this logo change caused on SO (and not only for supposed bigotry reasons but various different intricacies about the philosophy and legal underpinnings of SE). From an entirely pragmatic viewpoint you certainly *don't* want to change that logo.

Comment: @TARS - I didn't miss it. I did, however think that it was worth us considering.

Answer (score 22):

No. Whatever our personal feelings may be on the matter, the site should remain apolitical on an official level. Update your personal userpics if you wish.

Comment: +1; I'm glad at least one of the highly active users agrees with me on this!

Answer (score -9):

[image: VOLDEMORT]

Heck, yeah! I would support a logo change similar to SO's.

Comment: Better version; http://i.stack.imgur.com/q3JR7.gif

Comment: @Richard -- Feh! Taste is subjective! ;)

Comment: +1 Absolutely agreed!